# How to handle color codes when trying to use grep, sed, etc

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, grep

I'm trying to use sed to process some output of a command that is generating colored lines (it's git diff, but I don't think that's important). I'm trying to match a '+' sign at the beginning of the line but this is being confounded by the color code, which precedes the '+'. Is there a simple way to deal this this issue, or do I need to use some complicated regular expression to match the color code.

If possible I'd like to preserve the coloring of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must have the coloring then you're going to have to do something ugly:

```
$ git diff --color web-app/db/schema.rb |grep '^^[\[32m+
```

That `^[` is actually a raw escape character (<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>ESC</kbd> in bash, ASCII 27). You can use `cat -v` to figure out the necessary escape sequences:

```
$ git diff --color web-app/db/schema.rb |cat -v
^[[1mdiff --git a/web-app/db/schema.rb b/web-app/db/schema.rb^[[m
^[[1mindex 45451a2..411f6e1 100644^[[m
^[[1m--- a/web-app/db/schema.rb^[[m
^[[1m+++ b/web-app/db/schema.rb^[[m
...
```

This sort of thing will work fine with the GNU versions of `sed`, `awk`, ... YMMV with non-GNU versions.

An easier way would be to turn of the coloring:

```
$ git diff --no-color file
```

But you can trade pretty output for slightly ugly regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

No need to deal with ugly regular expressions, actually. You can just pass the config variable to the git command you're using to preserve coloring.

```
git -c color.diff=always diff | cat
```

This works for `git status` too

```
git -c color.status=always status -sb | cat
```

Comment: From what I'm seeing, this sort of works, but if the colorized line is edited it will then lose its color.

Answer (score 1):

This ugly expression should do it

`git diff --color src/Strmrs.h| grep $'^\(\x1b\[[0-9]\{1,2\}m\)\{0,1\}+'`

- The `$'...'` will make the \x1b into the ESC character (aka `^[`) - this can probably be avoided, I was too lazy to read the manpage
- the color sequence (ESC, left-bracket, 1-2 digits, and the letter `m`) are enclosed in outer set of `\(\)` which are then made optional with `\{0,1\}` the only non optional item is the last `+`.
- Assumes that there is at most one color sequence at the beginning of the line